# Python Sockets send Uint16 and Uint32

Tags: python, sockets, encoding, packed

I need to send a request via a python socket with the following structure:

```
{
   Uint16 data_one
   Uint16 data_one
   Uint32 data_one
}
```

I have my server and client working, but i do not really know how can i encode and decode this kind of data to send it over the socket. Thanks!

Comment: Use `struct.pack` to generate the bytestream and send it over the wire, then use `struct.unpack` on the other end to unpack the data.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you solved my problem @JanChristophTerasa !

Comment: I'll create an answer, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the functions in the [`struct` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html). Use `struct.pack` to generate the bytestream and send it over the wire, then use `struct.unpack` on the other end to unpack the data:

```
# sender
buffer = struct.pack('!3H', *data)
# ... send it


# receiver
# ... get the buffer
data = struct.unpack('!3H', buffer)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the Construct library: https://construct.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Similar but different to Protobuf, it allows you to define a "packed" data format, which is ideal when dealing with packed data formats, such as network packets or proprietary data formats.

```python
from construct import Struct, Int16ub, Int32ub

# Your data format
my_packet_struct = Struct(
    "field1" / Int16ub,
    "field2" / Int16ub,
    "field3" / Int32ub
)

# Some data you want serialise.
# The dict keys need to match those in the packet format above,
# but not necessarily the same order
my_data = {
    "field2": 321,
    "field1": 123,
    "field3": 999
}

# Serialise your data to bytes
my_serialised_bytes = my_packet_struct.build(my_data)
print("Serialised Bytes: {}".format(my_serialised_bytes.hex()))
# Send the data: socket.write(my_serialised_bytes)

# Deserialise to prove it works properly
my_deserialised_bytes = my_packet_struct.parse(my_serialised_bytes)

print("\nDeserialised object:")
print(my_deserialised_bytes)
```

Output:

```
Serialised Bytes: 007b0141000003e7

Deserialised object:
Container: 
    field1 = 123
    field2 = 321
    field3 = 999
```